# Natural language processing keywords for building search engine

Tags: nlp, nltk, search-engine, gensim, corpus

I'm recently interested in NLP, and would like to build up search engine for product recommendation. (Actually I'm always wondering about how search engine for Google/Amazon is built up)

Take Amazon product as example, where I could access all "word" information about one product:

```
Product_Name    Description      ReviewText
"XXX brand"    "Pain relief"    "This is super effective"
```

By applying `nltk` and `gensim` packages I could easily compare similarity of different products and make recommendations.

But here's another question I feel very vague about:
How to build a search engine for such products?

For example, if I feel pain and would like to search for medicine online, I'd like to type-in `"pain relief"` or `"pain"`, whose searching results should include `"XXX brand"`.

So this sounds more like keyword extraction/tagging question? How should this be done in NLP? I know **corpus** should contain **all** but **single** words, so it's like:

```
["XXX brand" : ("pain", 1),("relief", 1)]
```

So if I typed in either `"pain"` or `"relief"` I could get `"XXX brand"`; but what about I searched `"pain relief"`?

I could come up with idea that directly call python in my javascript for calculate similarities of input words `"pain relief"` on browser-based server and make recommendation; but that's kind of do-able?

I still prefer to build up very big lists of keywords at backends, stored in datasets/database and directly visualized in web page of search engine.

Thanks!

Comment: I think what you are looking for is an introduction to information retrieval (IR). Question answering (QA) might be a bit over the top. A document about a specific pain killer is very likely to talk a lot about pain relief, even if using a different phrasing (synonyms), so a query for "pain relief" should also give that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though this does not provide a full how-to answer, there are two things that might be helpful.

First, it's important to note that Google does **not** only treat singular words but also ngrams. 
More or less every NLP problem and therefore also information retrieval from text needs to tackle ngrams. This is because *phrases* carry way more expressiveness and information than singular tokens.

That's also why so called *NGramAnalyzers* are popular in search engines, be it Solr or elastic. Since both are based on Lucene, you should take a look [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_1_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/NGramTokenizer.html).

Relying on either framework, you can use a synonym analyser that adds for each word the synonyms you provide.
For example, you could add `relief = remedy` (and vice versa if you wish) to your synonym mapping. Then, both engines would retrieve relevant documents regardless if you search for "pain relief" or "pain remedy". However, you should probably also read [this post](http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2013/10/27/why-is-multi-term-synonyms-so-hard-in-solr/) about the issues you might encounter, especially when aiming for phrase synonyms.

Comment: Thanks so much. My purpose is to set up web-page that is very handy for users, who would only need to type-in and results pop out. So another question bothering me is,  how could I run my program(say, python) in Github browser server? Is it feasible? What I could think of is use jQuery/Ajax to send data back forth between javascript and python.

Comment: IMHO, setting up such an engine in the framework you describe is not feasible if you want to allow for more than a small number of users. Both query processing as well as the back end will require a more sophisticated setup.